# AttributeError - remove multiple whitespaces from multiple columns in dataframe

Tags: pandas

I do this:

```
df[['InfoType', 'InfoLabel1', 'InfoLabel2']] = df[['InfoType', 'InfoLabel1', 'InfoLabel2']].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split()))
```

and I receive this error:

AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'split'", 'occurred at index InfoType')

the columns `['InfoType', 'InfoLabel1', 'InfoLabel2']` simply have strings in their cells.

My goal is to remove multiple whitespaces and just put one whitespace in their place.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please show your df and expected output.

Comment: (@ggorlen, posting inputs and outputs is time-consuming and not necessary in many cases - another user already gave the correct answer to my question)

Comment: Sorry, that's not helpful to future visitors. Stack Overflow isn't just about _you_ getting an answer, it's about curating useful answers for everyone. If your data isn't clear, it's less useful. Posting a 3-4 line dataframe snippet and expected output frame isn't much to ask.

Comment: @ggorlen, I think that this is a useful post to everyone but anyway I am not going to debate on this now :)

Comment: @ggorlen is not wrong in any sense, a dummy input with an expected output takes very less time to post. and benificial to others, especially for users who are new to this technology/tag :) may be for future questions

Comment: @ggorlen, If you consider that my problem was not content-specific but it applied for all dataframes then I am not sure why not posting data inputs/outputs makes the post not useful enough :) - but I certainly agree that with data inputs/outputs it would be more complete.

Comment: @ggorlen, think more carefully about what I said. :)  I said `...not useful enough` while you say `...makes it more useful` . These two things are very different. And in any case I said `I certainly agree that with data inputs/outputs it would be more complete`. ;) 
(as for the bug in the answer - anyway someone who knows regex very well as you do knows how to remove multiple whitespaces without examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62307552/6243352) shows, you could use the regex `\s+` and replace with `" "` on each column of your dataframe. However, the behavior is different than `" ".join(x.split())`, which will trim leading and trailing whitespace.

Here's an example illustrating the difference:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = " foo bar    baz   "
>>> re.sub(r"\s+", " ", s)
' foo bar baz '
>>> " ".join(s.split())
'foo bar baz'
```

Since `apply` passes a `pandas.Series` object to each lambda function, calling `x.split()` on the object raises an `AttributeError`. If you want to preserve the `split`/`join` semantics shown above, you can use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to perform your function on each of the cells. Here's a minimal, reproducible example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> columns = ["InfoType", "InfoLabel1", "InfoLabel2"]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[" foo bar  baz  ", "a", " a "]], columns=columns)
>>> df
          InfoType InfoLabel1 InfoLabel2
0   foo bar  baz            a         a
>>> df[columns].applymap(lambda x: " ".join(x.split()))
      InfoType InfoLabel1 InfoLabel2
0  foo bar baz          a          a
```

Answer (score 3):

The `x` in your apply won't be the value of the individual cells, but rather a series (I think of each row). Hence your error.

Luckily for you, there is a much easier way to convert all white space into a single space, use regex and [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```py
text_features = [
    'InfoType', 
    'InfoLabel1', 
    'InfoLabel2',
]
df[text_features] = df[text_features].replace(regex=r"\s+", value=" ")
```

Comment: Thank you but are you sure this is exactly right? I receive this: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'` and indeed I think only series have `.str`

Comment: You're right, just leave off the `.str`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: nice solution, no need for apply..+1

Comment: `df[text_features].applymap(lambda x: " ".join(x.split()))` works if you want to use `apply` for cases when a regex might be insufficient.

Comment: Also, note that this will take leading and trailing spaces and squeeze them down to a single space whereas the `split` version above will trim leading and trailing space, so the two versions aren't exactly equivalent logically.